# Phonegap / Cordova Webview Send Event to Javascript

Tags: javascript, cordova, webview, phonegap-plugins

Our entire phonegap app is a wrapped webview of our HTML, CSS, JS web app. I'm trying to add 'share via' native functions for Android/iOS using the [SocialSharing](https://github.com/acasaccia/cordova-socialshare-plugin) plugin. For the life of me, I can't figure out how to send messages back to Phonegap/Cordova `index.html` from the webview.

The plugin is loaded in the `index.html` and I'm already launching the site from the phonegap `index.html` like so:

```
onDeviceReady: function () {    
  window.open('domain.com', '_self');
}
```

I've tried `window.postMessage`, `window.addEventListener` and using the now included `inAppBrowser` plugin.

I learned `inAppBrowser` can't communicate with cordova APIs so that was pointless but I figure there has to be a way to accomplish a seemingly simple feat.

How can I send messages from our webapp to the `index.html`? As always, thanks!

Comment: You can't, when you do the window.open('domain.com','_self'); you replace the index.html content with the domain.com content

Comment: @jcesar thanks, do you know of any other solutions?

Comment: I think you can point to a server changing the start url on the config.xml (changing <content src="index.html" /> to <content src="http://www.domain.com/index.html" />), and then if you have the cordova.js on the server, it might work